# GIMP Script-Fu: "Error: <: argument 1 must be: number"

Tags: scheme, gimp, script-fu

I'm having an issue with writing a GIMP Script that applies a drop shadow. So this is how the script looks when you pull it from the console:

```
(script-fu-drop-shadow run-mode image drawable value value value color value toggle)
```

And these are the values I've entered:

```
(script-fu-drop-shadow 1 image layer 0 0 3 '(115.9 200.9 245.1) 1 0)
```

When I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
Execution error for 'MUA Portrait Outline - Blue Glow':
Error: <: argument 1 must be: number
```

I think I'm not really understanding all the values that I need to enter.

1. `run-mode` is straightforward, since it says to either use 1 or 0.
2. Based on prior scripts I've tried, I'm pretty sure that I leave `image` as `image` since it's just for the current image.
3. I'm not too sure what `drawable` is, but I read that drawables include layers, so I put `layer`. Not sure if that's accurate.
4. The next 3 `value` variables are for the x offset, y offset, and blur radius. Straightforward.
5. I'm not too sure if I'm entering `color` correctly as I've never actually used a script that asks for the color, but I think I did it correctly just based on some research I did online.
6. The last `value` variable is also straightforward, as it's the opacity of the shadow.
7. I have no clue what to set for `toggle`. It says it accepts `INT32` for that, so I figured I would just put 0. I tried to do some online research, but I couldn't find anything

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm not well-versed in Script-fu. I've tried a few things here and there, but I don't know much formal stuff. Feel free to explain things as simply as possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find numbers of current image and current drawable (if you are working with multiple images, these don't have to be `1` and `3`), then call it without `run-mode`:

```
> (gimp-image-list) 
(1 #(1)) <-- All images, current image is one number from vector #(1)

> (gimp-image-get-active-drawable 1)
(3) <-- Current drawable of current image

> (script-fu-drop-shadow 1 3 0 0 20 '(255 0 0) 100 0)
(#t)
```

If you don't know meaning of some arguments, you can check `Procedure Browser` (`Help → Procedure Browser`)- `toggle` argument is *Allow resizing* and you can also use `TRUE` or `FALSE` as value, because they evaluate to `1` or `0` respectively.

**EDIT:** If you want run this as .scm script, follow these steps:

- .scm file should look like this:

```
(define (script-fu-my-script image drawable)
    (script-fu-drop-shadow image drawable 0 0 20 '(255 0 0) 100 0))

(script-fu-register "script-fu-my-script"
  _"Add _Drop _Shadow..."
  _"Add drop shadow"
  "Author's name"
  "Author's name"
  "12/9/21"
  "*"
  SF-IMAGE       "Input image" 0
  SF-DRAWABLE    "Input drawable" 0)

(script-fu-menu-register "script-fu-my-script"
                         "<Image>/My_Scripts/Drop")
```

- Find correct folder for your scripts: `Edit -> Preferences -> Folders -> Scripts` and move your .scm file to one from these folders.
- Restart GIMP or refresh your scripts: `Filters -> Script-Fu -> Refresh Scripts`
- Right click on image, `My Scripts -> Drop -> Add Drop Shadow`.

Comment: With proper script registration, image and target drawable are passed as arguments.

Comment: I'm getting the same error with this that I described below to xenoid. I'm trying to get this to run in a .scm script rather than through the console, but I tried to use it in the console and got the same error. When I called the image list thing, it gave me `(1 #(5))`, but putting 1 and 5 as the first 2 arguments gives me the error again.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you! I think the issue was probably me not defining the "drawable" in the first line

Answer (score 0):

It works if you drop the `run-mode` argument.

```
(script-fu-drop-shadow 1 3 3 3 3  '(115 200 245) 50 0)
```

Don't ask me why, I write my scripts in Python :)

For that matter most of the code in that script is handling things that mostly make sense when using it interactively. In most case your code can do it by selecting alpha, adding a layer, filling the selection, blurring it and adjusting the offset.

Comment: When I use this for my script, it gives me 2 errors:

```Calling error for procedure 'gimp-drawable-type-with-alpha':
Procedure 'gimp-drawable-type-with-alpha' has been called with an invalid ID for argument 'drawable'. Most likely a plug-in is trying to work on a layer that doesn't exist any longer.```

(posting 2 comments because of text limit)

Comment: ```Execution error for 'MUA Portrait Outline - Blue Glow':
Error: Procedure execution of gimp-drawable-type-with-alpha failed on invalid input arguments: Procedure 'gimp-drawable-type-with-alpha' has been called with an invalid ID for argument 'drawable'. Most likely a plug-in is trying to work on a layer that doesn't exist any longer. ```

Comment: Where does "drawable" come from? What is the value? This should be another question anyway, in which you would include your source code. And please considering upvoting/accepting the answers you have received here ince they fixed your initial problem.